# Regex for Currency Amount with D for negative amounts or C for positive amounts

Tags: regex, currency

I need help with RegEx.

Valid values:

```
-1.00 D
-2,000.00 D
-100,000.56 D
-100,000.00 D
-1,123,456.43 D

1.00 C
2,000.00 C
100,000.56 C
100,000.00 C
1,123,456.43 C
```

Before Decimal (Whole Numbers) can be upto 13 digits. Decimal should be always 2 digits.

> -ve values will have SPACE and then D

and

> +ve values will have SPACE and then C

Please help.

Comment: which regex engine are you using?  what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use a look ahead to assert the overall format:

```
^(?=-.{,21}D|\d.{,20}C)-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d\d [CD]$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/xiQ4ZfnSPI7qfF).

Comment: @Cary indeed! All fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression to verify that strings match the pattern.

```
^(?=-.*D$|\d.*C$)-?(?=(?:\d,?){1,13}\.)(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*)\.\d{2} [DC]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IGfmAH/2/)

I tested this with the PCRE regex engine but it should work with any engine the supports lookaheads.

The regex contains two *positive lookaheads*. The first asserts that the string begins with a hyphen or digit; if a hyphen the last character must be `D`, if a digit the last character must be `C`. The second lookahead asserts that the string contains 1-13 digits before the decimal point.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                match beginning of line
```

```
(?=              begin positive lookahead
  -.*D$          match '-', 0+ chars, 'D' at end of line
  |              or
  \d.*C$         match 1 digit, 0+ chars, 'C' at end of line
)                end positive lookahead
```

```
-?               optionally match '-'
```

```
(?=              begin positive lookahead
  (?:\d,?)       match 1 digit optionally followed by ','
                 in a non-capture group
  {1,13}         execute preceding non-capture group 1-13 times
  \.             match '.'
)                end positive lookahead
```

```
(?:              begin non-capture group
  0              match '0' for amounts < '1.00'
  |              or
  [1-9]\d{0,2}   optionally match '-', then match one digit
                 other than '0', then 0-2 digits   
  (?:,\d{3})     match ',' then 3 digits in non-capture group
  *              execute preceding non-capture group 0+ times
)                end non-capture group
\.\d{2} [DC]     match '.', 2 digits, 1 space 'D' or 'C'
$                match end of string
```

The end-of-line anchors in the first lookahead are actually not necessary (because of the end-of-line anchor at the end of the regex), but I've included them to improve readability.